# Using of JQuery Deferred Promises for Caching

Tags: jquery, caching, express, promise, jquery-deferred

---

While looking at the potential use cases for JQuery Deferred Promises, I came across Caching as one of the potential uses. That brought about the following question: While using modern browsers and smart clients (Jquery, any modern MVC, etc.,) do I even have to worry about caching anything myself? I am working with MEAN stack and I am under the impression that caching does happen by default.  There is an Etag field in the headers that ensures that the server doesn't send the same information twice. The 2nd time, client will get 304 code with empty response body.  So are there any use cases out there requiring to manually implement caching on the front end?  Thanks!

Comment: you might find this presentation interesting: http://www.slideshare.net/RayBellis/memoizing-withindexeddb

Comment: You don't always want to cache the exact sever response - often you want to cache part of the data, or processed information.

Answer (score 1):

The whole concept of Promises is targeted at making simpler the handling of asynchronous computations for JavaScript programmers. I could imagine a valid use-case, when you serve some predefined data with rejected promises, but that's not what you call "caching".

If you have a deferred object that handles some kind of request to asynchronous API, it's up to you to implement a caching layer for static data, it might be a part of your `.then()` function. The browser will send as many requests to the API as you have in your code and the server will respond with the same amount of responses, unless it has it's own caching layer.

[Here is an example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51651/what-is-the-best-approach-to-cache-memoize-promise-results) of usage of Memoization for caching data from asynchronous computations.

```
// *specialized* function for, say, network requests,
// where caching is desired. In this case, we're caching
// promises by the URL they're fetching
var fetch = (function () {
  var cache = {};
  return function (url) {
    cache[url] = cache.hasOwnProperty(url) ? cache[url] : new Promise(
      /* request magic goes here */
    );
    return cache[url];
  };
});
```

**TL:DR**

You don't use Promises for caching, you  implement your own caching layer for your asynchronous computations(you can use Memoization pattern for that). It doesn't matter if you use Deferred objects for that or regular callbacks.